# How to improve the chance to stop a hunter in Left 4 Dead 2?

Tags: left-4-dead-2

I played L4D2 online with people that stop **Hunters** from getting them almost always.
Instead, they get me 7-8 out of 10 times. How can I improve my chances to block hunters?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can melee a hunter mid-leap to cancel its attack and stun it.  It requires some practice on the timing to get it perfect, but it's extremely effective, especially since the hunter is so loud before it pounces.  Learn to identify the different sounds each infected make so you know what to prepare for.

After you stun it, you can deal with it however you see fit.  If you melee it enough times that will kill it too, and is a satisfying way to taunt hunters who get too close to you.

Answer (score 9):

If you mean a dead stop (melee as he's pouncing), then there is a trick: Hunter's box model (the wire-frame model responsible for hit-testing) is way before his rendered body.

So if you want to dead stop him you should time your melee just before it gets to you.

Whether the melee connects depends also on your ping to the server. Remember, hit-testing takes place on the server and server only on online games.

Also, bot hunters can cheat by clawing you while stunned, so make short work of them with your rifle as they are stunned and don't go in for another melee.

Update: [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKKQmdRFIgY) demonstrates the difference between the hitbox model and the what-you-see model.

Comment: Valve games typically use [lag compensation](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking#Lag_compensation), so while it's true hit-testing takes place on the server, lag compensation minimizes how much you need to "lead" your target, including melee, because of your latency. Then again, I don't know if Valve uses that techniques for hunters in L4D.

Comment: @Oak: Lag compensation doesn't help here. This can be observed even on single player campaign.

Answer (score 3):

if you hit in exactly right second the hunter will fall back.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can sidestep them if (you see them coming), or just shoot them in midair.

Comment: Kind of a no brainer, but beware: Good players will make a curved flight to prevent getting shot down in midair, so you don't stand a chance much moving around, if there is no place to hide near you.

Answer (score 0):

Try jumping and shoving him. It works for me 90% of the time. I've only tried it in Single Player. Not sure if it works for versus though.